# Group by and merge multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table like that :

```
group    subgroup     date           action
A         a           09/09/2017       ok
A         b           17/10/2018       ko
A         c           17/11/2018       wait
A         d           21/12/2018       no-action
B         e           11/12/2020       nok
B         f           13/11/2019       wait
```

So for this set I want to get only one row by Group
so for example group A contains an action with "ok" I want to keep only this row

else if the set doesn't contain the action ok, I need to keep the row with max of date

I tried lot of things but I'm not able to get what I expected,

```
group           date           action
    A          09/09/2017       ok
    B          11/12/2020       nok
```

Comment: Please don't tag multiple RDBMS, just pick the right one which is the one you are working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   "group" varchar(50),
   subgroup varchar(50),
   "date" date,
   action varchar(50)
);


insert into T values ('A','a','2017/09/09','ok');
insert into T values ('A','b','2018/10/17','ko');
insert into T values ('A','c','2018/11/17','wait');
insert into T values ('A','d','2018/12/21','no-action');
insert into T values ('B','e','2020/12/11','nok');
insert into T values ('B','f','2019/11/13','wait');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT "group",date,"action" FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "group" order by case when action = 'ok' then 1 else 2 end,date desc) rn
    FROM T
)t1
where rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2dc39/1/0)**:

```
| group |       date | action |
|-------|------------|--------|
|     A | 2017-09-09 |     ok |
|     B | 2020-12-11 |    nok |
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with prioritization:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by group 
                                order by case when action = 'ok' then 1 else 2 end,
                                         date
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```